# How can I break lines in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]

As seen in the image, the text is too long, I want to split it into two lines.

how can I add something like newline \n in text or other methods, wrap value seems doesn't take effect for me.

Blender 3.5

Comment: "normally" this works, did you add spaces? i think Blender "breaks" only at spaces

Answer (score 2):

The Wrap value can be used to break lines, but it is not a good solution if you need more line breaks.
The thing is that the string actually supports chr(13) as line breaks, but there is no manual way to enter a line break key.
This can however be done with an add-on, or I've actually made 3 add-ons which can insert strings with the line break:

- Text Strip Editor: https://github.com/tin2tin/Subtitle_Editor
- Text Block to Text Strip: https://github.com/tin2tin/import_text_block_as_text_strip
- Text Editor to Text Strip: https://github.com/tin2tin/text_to_strip